# Unmarshal JSON date string to BSON date in Golang

Tags: mongodb, go, marshalling, unmarshalling, bson

This should be easy but I'm not making much headway.  Say I have JSON with a UTC date like this:

```
{
  "name": "Lex",
  "dob": "2022-11-01T06:30:30.639326208Z"
}
```

I'd like to insert it in a MongoDB collection. In Go, I do:

```
import (
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
)

...

var doc any
// by the way what does the 2nd param do?  docs don't mention it
_ = bson.UnmarshalExtJSON(jsonBytes, false, &doc)
mongoCollection.InsertOne(context.TODO(), doc)
```

The insert works, but the `dob` field is just a string.  What's the correct way to insert it as Date?  My constraints are:

1. I cannot change the input JSON
2. I can't manually write the Mongo doc because I could be dealing with large unpredictable objects and won't know which fields/nested fields have a date string

Is this doable? Seems like there has to be a paved road for how to do this.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks. So if I hear you, I have to know ahead of time which fields should be transformed to `Date`?  Ok suppose I know there's a `dob` field.  What would I do? I'm guessing edit the `doc` after the unmarshal line?

Answer (score 2):

You could define one custom decoders of [`bsoncodec.ValueDecoder`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/bsoncodec#ValueDecoder) to decode the date string to `time.Time`, then register it through [`RegisterTypeDecoder`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/bsoncodec#RegistryBuilder.RegisterTypeDecoder)

```golang
func dateTimeDecodeValue(dc bsoncodec.DecodeContext, vr bsonrw.ValueReader, val reflect.Value) error {
    ts, _ := vr.ReadString()
    t, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339Nano, ts)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    } 

    val.Set(reflect.ValueOf(t))

    return nil
}

var tDateTime = reflect.TypeOf(time.Time{})

type TestDoc struct {
    Name string    `bson:"name"`
    Dob  time.Time `bson:"dob"`
}

func createCustomRegistry() *bsoncodec.RegistryBuilder {
    var primitiveCodecs bson.PrimitiveCodecs

    rb := bsoncodec.NewRegistryBuilder()
    bsoncodec.DefaultValueEncoders{}.RegisterDefaultEncoders(rb)
    bsoncodec.DefaultValueDecoders{}.RegisterDefaultDecoders(rb)
    rb.RegisterTypeDecoder(tDateTime, bsoncodec.ValueDecoderFunc(dateTimeDecodeValue))
    primitiveCodecs.RegisterPrimitiveCodecs(rb)
    return rb
}
```

Or to parse date string to BSON date sample codes

```golang
func dateTimeDecodeValue(dc bsoncodec.DecodeContext, vr bsonrw.ValueReader, val reflect.Value) error {
    ts, _ := vr.ReadString()
    t, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339Nano, ts)
    if err != nil {
        val.SetString(ts)
    } else {
        val.Set(reflect.ValueOf(primitive.DateTime(t.UnixMilli())))
    }

    return nil
}

var tDateTime = reflect.TypeOf(primitive.DateTime(0))

type TestDoc struct {
    Name string             `bson:"name"`
    Dob  primitive.DateTime `bson:"dob"`
}

func createCustomRegistry() *bsoncodec.RegistryBuilder {
    var primitiveCodecs bson.PrimitiveCodecs

    rb := bsoncodec.NewRegistryBuilder()
    bsoncodec.DefaultValueEncoders{}.RegisterDefaultEncoders(rb)
    bsoncodec.DefaultValueDecoders{}.RegisterDefaultDecoders(rb)
    rb.RegisterTypeDecoder(tDateTime, bsoncodec.ValueDecoderFunc(dateTimeDecodeValue))
    primitiveCodecs.RegisterPrimitiveCodecs(rb)
    return rb
}
```

Then use this register through [`UnmarshalExtJSONWithRegistry`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#UnmarshalExtJSONWithRegistry)

```golang
func main() {
    jsonBytes := []byte(`{
       "name": "ben",
       "dob": "2022-11-01T06:30:30.639326208Z"
    }`)

    var customRegistry = createCustomRegistry().Build()

    var doc TestDoc
    _ = bson.UnmarshalExtJSONWithRegistry(customRegistry, jsonBytes, false, &doc)
    fmt.Println(doc)
}
```

Full codes
<kbd>[PLAYGROUND](https://go.dev/play/p/ZEb0vjwV4qV)</kbd>

---

As for `Canonical` parameter please refer to [doc](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/extended-json.rst#canonical-extended-json-example)

> Canonical Extended JSON - A string format based on the JSON standard that describes BSON documents. Canonical Extended JSON emphasizes type preservation at the expense of readability and interoperability.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!  Your decode function never executes.  To get it to run I changed the type passed to  `RegisterTypeDecoder` from `tDateTime` to `reflect.TypeOf("")`.  It runs, but when it gets to the `val.Set(reflect.ValueOf(primitive.DateTime(t.UnixMilli())))` it throws panic `"reflect.Set: value of type primitive.DateTime is not assignable to type string"`

Comment: @BeetleJuice, since the `tDateTime` to `reflect.TypeOf("")`, it means the type of `Dob` of `TestDoc` should be `string`  rather than `primitive.DateTime`.

Comment: @BeetleJuice, It is so weird that decode function never executes, please find the code here https://go.dev/play/p/ZEb0vjwV4qV

Comment: Thanks so much for your time.  Your code works just as you said. I think I understand why your decoder wasn't triggered in my case.  Your struct has a `primitive.Datetime` for `dob`, so the string is correctly read into that field as Datetime; but I don't know the shape I'm unmarshaling into ahead of time.  I'm getting an unknown JSON shape in bytes, so I'm unmarshaling into an `any` type.  Notice constraint #2 in my original post

Comment: @BeetleJuice Sorry for missing some information in your question. IMO, since you won't know which fields/nested fields have a date string, maybe it could be better to unmarshal original data to `map[string]interface{}`, rather than `any` type. You could not get any information from `any` type.